# WithHeader do not works while trying to add User-Agent

Tags: c#, flurl

I am trying to add an agent to `Flurl(Flurl.Http.2.4.2)` request using the code below

```
var url = new Url(downloadUrl);
url.WithHeader("User-Agent", "MyAgent/1.9");
var response = await url.GetAsync();
```

Unfortunately, the only header which is sent is

```
{
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}
```

How to add an agent to a request?

Comment: Try `var url = new Url(...).WithHeader(...);` or `var url = new Url(...); url = url.WithHeader(...);`?

Comment: @canton7 Works as expected! Thanks.

Comment: So, the lesson there is that `WithHeader` returns a new object which contains the header, rather than mutating the object it's called on. That's common practice for methods whose names start with "With" (but not universal)

Answer (score 0):

Fluent's Url object is just an implementation of the [builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), a clever way to permit the creation of an object with many optional parameters without polluting its constructor.

This means that the WithHeader method return the builder object itself, with its internal state changed to reflect the fact that you added an Header.

Now, to resolve your problem you need to assign the result of the WithHeader call again to your variable.
Instead of this:

```
var url = new Url(downloadUrl);
url.WithHeader("User-Agent", "MyAgent/1.9");
```

you should do this:

```
var url = new Url(downloadUrl);
url = url.WithHeader("User-Agent", "MyAgent/1.9");
```

or (preferably) this:

```
var url = new Url(downloadUrl).WithHeader("User-Agent", "MyAgent/1.9");
```

Which is the more common approach to consume a builder.